# I want to use a depth first search recursively to get an object's value using the key which might be nested in that object in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, recursion, depth-first-search

I have this object, and I want to get the 'user' key's value, I usually can use a for loop to get the value, what if that key I am searching for is nested in another object? How can I write a recursive JS function that automatically gets the key/value I am looking for?

````
  "http://converge.amwell.com/claims": {
    "ehr": "DEMO-CVSHI-EPIC-1",
    "connection": "con_9ydmEmrkyPulwlwU",
    "role": "PATIENT",
    "tenant": "CVSHI",
    "user": "b3e9c94d-18e4-4743-9f4e-fe7e251e7b17",
    "patient": "b3e9c94d-18e4-4743-9f4e-fe7e251e7b17",
    "id_type": "INTERNAL_FHIR"
  },
  "iss": "https://amwellstage.amwell-dev.auth0.com/",
  "sub": "oauth2|CVSHI-PATIENT|sick-cost@16xkn1tf.mailosaur.net",
  "aud": [
    "https://amwellstage.amwell-dev.auth0.com/api/v2/",
    "https://amwellstage.amwell-dev.auth0.com/userinfo"
  ],
  "iat": 1665480351,
  "exp": 1665481251,
  "azp": "cKftX4PfLpO0gFULuQiyDiX57BtTbpwg",
  "scope": "openid profile email offline_access",
  "org_id": "org_HMAePTi76uUGOfdG"
}```

```for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {

    //     if (key === 'user') {

    //         user = value
    //     }

    //     if (value instanceof Object) {

    //         for (const [subKey, subValue] of Object.entries(value)) {

    //             if (subKey === 'user') {

    //                 user = subValue

    //             }

    //         }

    //     }

    // }```
````

Comment: Where's your recursive function? Please show us your attempt.

Comment: Can you provide the full object?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
function getPropFromObj(obj, prop) {
    let valueToFindByKey;
    if (!Array.isArray(obj) && obj !== null && typeof obj === "object") {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {

            valueToFindByKey = obj[prop];
            console.log(valueToFindByKey);
        } else {

            let i;
            for (i = 0; i < Object.keys(obj).length; i++) {


                getPropFromObj(obj[Object.keys(obj)[i]], prop);
            }
        }

    }
    return null;

}


getPropFromObj(obj, "user");
```

The above `getPropFromObj` will do a deep search on the object and pull the value defined by the given key.

Hope it helps.